# TS2739 assignment of an interface type variable to concrete variable

Tags: typescript

interface and concrete type variables are interchangeable, although I have defined name in the class and the interface, but the compiler is complaining.

### Interface IBar

```
interface IBar { // IP
    readonly name: string;
}
```

### Class Bar

```
class Bar implements IBar { // P
    protected readonly _name: string;

    public get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

## Use

```
let bar = new Bar(); // concrete type
let factory: () => IBar = () => new Bar(); // interface type

// assigning an interface type result to concrete type var
bar = factory(); // TS2739: Type IBar is missing the following properties from type Bar: _name, name
```

Attached Screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line `let bar = new Bar();`
you are actually saying that bar is of type Bar, and then you are trying to assign to it an instance of IBar (that is just inicidentally a Bar at runtime, but not on the type level where it's IBar) later when calling factory.

If you were to do:

`let bar: IBar = new Bar();`

or (though I assume you don't want this)

`let factory: () => Bar = () => new Bar();`

this would fix the issue.

Comment: I assume, concrete types and interface types are interchangable. I could assignment either way without any problem, assign an interface to a concrete, and concrete to an interface.

Comment: @Source - `Bar` is a *subtype* of `IBar` (it has a different shape, not least that it has a `_name` property [which matters even though it isn't public]). Since `Bar` *is a* `IBar`, you can assign `Bar` values to `IBar`-typed variables, but you can't assign `IBar` values to `Bar`-typed variables, because they don't have the right shape (no `_name` property in this case). As Matjia8 said, if you're explicit about the `bar` variable being of type `IBar` by giving it a type annotation, you're fine, because then you're assigning an `IBar` value (as far as the compiler knows) to an `IBar` variable.

Comment: I see, so I misunderstood. In summary, interface types can hold a concrete type, but a concrete type can't hold an interface type. I guess because there could be other kinds of concrete implementations of the interface.

Comment: @Source - *"but a concrete type can't hold an interface type"* It's not about "concrete" vs. "interface," it's about *shape*. [Here's your example where `IBar`'s shape can be assigned to an `Bar`-typed variable](https://tsplay.dev/WJrovW). TypeScript's type system is *structural*, it's all about the *shapes* of types (what properties they have and of what types). Whether that type is defined via `interface`, `type`, or indirectly via `class` (`class` defines both a type and an implementation of that type) is irrelevant.

Comment: Essentially, they have a mirror of each other in terms of properties and methods to be interchangeable. Thanks for the playground example.